# Disable annoying flashing in IE 6 / 7

Tags: internet-explorer, windows-xp

I am currently working on a project for embedded WinXp. The application refresh a HTML Site every 5 Seconds. The problem is that I am using IE 6 / 7 by spec. But the browser have this annoying blinking and the customer dont like it.

Chrome, Firefox and so on just refresh the page like a charm but IE dont.

Is there a way to disable this problem ?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Can you edit the html? If so, add

```
<meta http-equiv="Page-Enter" content="blendTrans(Duration=0)">
```

to the html `<head>` tag.

Answer (score 2):

That's just the way IE handles page refreshes, the page will be white for a moment. If you want to get rid of the flash, you need to reload the page via AJAX, which might be overkill for your project. In my own opinion, you should assure your customer that there's no way to get rid of it. And anyways, if this software is going to an embedded system, why does it have to support IE?

Comment: The customer only trust MS products. Anyway I think so.

Comment: Then it's your job to convince the customer that to get the best possible outcome, best possible tools should be used. In this case, IE is not the best.